# broken handler for custom handlers

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 with views 3.

I have defined a custom handler for a field and is working on my development machine. When I revert same view in live environment I am getting issue of broken handler, even the handler class s present.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are your module with custom handler enabled? Are you using the same version of Views on both sites? Try to flush caches twice.

Comment: Yes the module is enabled and everything is working with out this field handler. I am using views 3 in both dev and demo environments. I have cleared cache many times and even rebuild registry.

Comment: Is the path to the file containing the handler's code relative ? By any means, it would help to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by using hook_views_data_alter(). Earlier the custom handler for the select field was defined in hook_views_data().

Comment: where would change this piece of code Umar?